# Can the controls in the toolbox be used in both Winform and WPF application?

Tags: wpf, winforms

If not, how can I know which controls are used in winforms, which controls are used in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you develop a WinForms application, WPF controls are not shown in your toolbox, and vice versa.

If you want to use a WinForms control in a WPF application anyway, there's the `WindowsFormsHost` WPF control for that.
For hosting a WPF control in a Windows Forms app, you can use the `System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost` control.

Answer (score 0):

The toolboxes already filter what controls you can use depending on whether you have created a Win Form or a WPF application project.